# Button Action Events

Tags: swift3, xcode8, ios10

The user needs to press a button to show label contents and hide again when the button is released. 
With the following, the label is shown when the user press the button but stay shown after the user releases the button.

```
myLabel.isHidden = true
```

and

```
@IBAction func myButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    myLabel.isHidden = false
```

Any help is more than welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create 2 IbActions for the button. When you create theses actions you can change the event. One needs to be Touch Down and one need to be Touch Up Inside.

[image]

Once you have the 2 actions you can then simply hide and show the label in each of the actions.

```
//Touch Down Event added to this action
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) { 
    print("Button Pressed") 
    myLabel.isHidden = false
}

//Touch Up Inside Event added to this action
@IBAction func buttonReleased(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("Button Released") 
    myLabel.isHidden = true
}
```

Comment: Hi Luke, for some reason in your way, does not show myLabel contents, if I change false/true order it shows myLabel only when released :(

Comment: Have you created to action for the button each with different events? (Touch Down, Touch Up Inside).

Comment: Yes two actions in the same button

Comment: Iv added print statements into the actions. Run the app and check the log for the messages. One should print when the button is pressed and the other when its released.

Comment: Can you add your project or more code so i can see exactly what you have. This should work for you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142516/discussion-between-manolo-and-luke-chase).

Comment: Follow your instructions and delete all references now it is working thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 2):

you need to use the touch down method to hide the label and use touch up inside to show it again.

```
  @IBAction func touchUpInside(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("inside")
    label.isHidden = true
  }

  @IBAction func touchDown(_ sender: Any) {
    print("touch down")
    label.isHidden = false
  }
```

Comment: Hi rameez, the label is hidden by default, should only appears while the button is pressed

Comment: Yes you can add these events and check it works. The label is shown while the button is pressed and hidden when you release it.

Comment: it shows the label contents when I release the button :(

Comment: The contents of the label comes from a array.

Comment: You can test my sample in the repo [here](https://github.com/rameeznkhan/ButtonTest)

Comment: Connection=Action, Type=UIButton, Event=TouchDown, Arguments=Sender

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142513/discussion-between-manolo-and-rameez).